# How do I match two separate words as one string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which contains the names of US states and countries, and a list which also contains these. I would like to create a function which returns the state/country if it finds it. So far, I have been able to do this for anything which is one word long, eg 'Brazil' or 'Mexico'. However, the function does not match for instances which are more than word long, eg 'new york' or ''cayman islands'.

My function:

```
#alpha_list is my list of countries and US states

def locate_country(b):
    y = b.split(" ")
    a = [x for x in alpha_list if x in y]
    return a

df['country'] = df['locations'].apply(locate_country)
```

Is there a way to adapt this so it captures two-words too?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `str.extract` here along with an alternation of locations:

```py
alpha_list = ["Brazil", "Mexico", "Channel Islands"]
regex = r'\b(' + r'|'.join(alpha_list) + r')\b'
df["country"] = df["locations"].str.extract(regex)
```

Comment: Thanks - does this return the location identified?

Comment: @work_python I misread/misunderstood your requirement.  I have updated my answer such that the new `country` column will contain a country, if a match were found.  Otherwise it should be empty/NaN.

Comment: Thank you! I receive the error 'Columns must be same length as value key' when I use the updated function- any idea why this might be?

Comment: You don't need a function, nor does my answer use one.  If you run my answer directly, it should be working.

Comment: That is what I did but I receive the error I mentioned above

Comment: Just to add, str.contains(regex) works in that it says True or False, but the extract version returns the error I mentioned.